# Attaching casbah source in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, scala, casbah

I am having trouble attaching the source for the mongodb casbah library in eclipse. I couldn't find a source jar anywhere, so I downloaded the source from [github](https://github.com/mongodb/casbah), but I didn't know what the appropriate branch/version would be, so I just used the latest from master -- I suspect that's my problem.

I am working on a play project and my Build.scala file contains this:

```
"org.mongodb" %% "casbah" % "2.6.1"
```

Comment: Are you using `sbteclipe` to generate project files? it supports an option `with-sources=true`

Comment: I am using "play eclipsify" which doesn't seem to have that options.

Comment: It seems `play eclipse` should do the trick, if you're using Play 2.1. It's based on sbteclipse and supports `with-sources`

Comment: I'm stuck with play 2.0.4 for now. I tried play ecplisify with-sources=true and I get "Not a valid key"

Answer (score 0):

Due to how casbah is packaged and split up there is a parent transparent pom file which just lists the casbah module dependencies.  As this doesn't play nice with ide's there is now an all dependencies jar.

For more information see the [casbah documentation](http://mongodb.github.io/casbah/alternative_install#all-dependencies-jar) - add that to your library / sources path and you should be good to go.

Comment: I tried those. I got "The source attachment does not contain the source for MongoClient$.class" for all three.

Comment: A the commandline I have scala 2.9.2. I assume (hopefully correctly) that that's the same vers eclipse is using.